# Boostrap div elements don't align well

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found a really tricky problem for bootstrap div in responsive design.

my code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Grid System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap- theme.min.css">
<script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
<style type="text/css">
    p{
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Open the output in a new blank tab (Click the arrow next to "Show Output" button) and resize the window to understand how the Bootstrap responsive grid system works. -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 1 test</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 2</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 3</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 4</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 5</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 6</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 7</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 8</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 9</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 10</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 11</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 12</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you try this code in HTML, in a medium sized screen, you will see obviously the Box 7 shows under Box 2 instead of under Box 1. that's because Box 1 have extra strings: test.

So I would like to know if there's a way to make them aligned well? like Box 7 shows under Box 1 and so on...

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Close the `row` up after box 6, then add a new row.

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 1 test</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 2</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 3</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 4</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 5</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 6</p></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 7</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 8</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 9</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 10</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 11</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 12</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/rOqxNd/)

Comment: This works too. however, in my situation, I use angularjs ng-repeat to render all results, and the text is derived from database, so I don't know where it might have a taller column, what should I do then?

Comment: It will work, the problem is that bootstrap is a 12 col grid system, you were adding too many cols to a row.

Comment: In AngularJS, my code is like this:
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2" ng-repeat="item in items">
              <p>{{item.title}}</p>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
So I think I cannot group every 6 of them in a single <div class="row">. I know with angularjs it's already a new question, but please help me if you know the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry you can mark a correct answer then ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

> A clearfix is a way for an element to automatically clear its child
>   elements, so that you don't need to add additional markup. It's
>   generally used in float layouts where elements are floated to be
>   stacked horizontally. The clearfix is a way to combat the zero-height
>   container problem for floated elements. > From this SO Post [What is clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

You can use the `clearfix` class by applying it after the last div for the specified columns (since you want 6 col-md-2s for 12 total columns). In this case apply it after the sixth `col-md-2`.

See the [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/850x350" class="img-responsive" />
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        <p>Box 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/850x250" class="img-responsive" />
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        <p>Box 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/850x550" class="img-responsive" />
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        <p>Box 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/850x650" class="img-responsive" />
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        <p>Box 4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/850x350" class="img-responsive" />
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        <p>Box 5</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/850x550" class="img-responsive" />
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        <p>Box 6</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/850x450" class="img-responsive" />
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        <p>Box 7</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/850x350" class="img-responsive" />
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        <p>Box 8</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/850x250" class="img-responsive" />
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        <p>Box 9</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/850x500" class="img-responsive" />
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        <p>Box 10</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/850x400" class="img-responsive" />
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        <p>Box 11</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/850x350" class="img-responsive" />
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        <p>Box 12</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is a cool way. However, in my case, the text is derived from database, and angular ng-repeat is used to render all the results. Plus, because each div is responsive, the taller columns happened only in certain window sizes. So I don't know where to add the clearfix div. How do we deal with this situation?